# GKE: Sharing the same filesystem across pods

Tags: storage, google-cloud-storage

I'm quite new and try to get my head around kubernetes and GKE so here it goes:

I would like an application to write data to a persistent storage.

If I'd scale up, or down, or a pod dies,
I'd like this persistent storage to survive.

Also, the same data should be available to different pods.

How do I achieve this?

The data are images, so storing them in a database could be a valid solution for this case,
but I wondered whether - if data is big - there are also solutions with filesystems 
to achieve this...

Thanks for answering,

S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a pretty n00b question :(

I suppose you'd need a pod which manages the filesystem,
and make it available to the other pods which need the functionality to store data on it...

Br,

S.